Trouble with a 'EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE' call in windows (probably due to 'cmd.exe' behavior)
I have commands that I want to run in succession to generate reports using Fortran. I'm having a problem getting Windows to properly execute the command via EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE. A sample of the commands are as follows:
 "M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /f "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv" > "D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-FLU.html"
 "M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /d "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv" > "D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-DCS.html"
 "M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /i "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv" > "D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-TWE.html"

A double quoted command, it's argument switches, a double quoted input file argument, an '>' to redirect stdout, and a double quoted output file argument. Supposedly simple enough.
Whenever I pass one of these commands to 'EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE', I get,
"The specified path is invalid." from the OS.
If I list the commands instead make them as a batch file, it runs as expected, with the following output:
 C:\Users\dle\OneDrive - TransWare Enterprises Inc\Documents\Code Blocks workspaces\Fortran\reportgen>"M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /f "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv"  1>"D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-FLU.html" 

C:\Users\dle\OneDrive - TransWare Enterprises Inc\Documents\Code Blocks workspaces\Fortran\reportgen>"M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /d "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv"  1>"D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-DCS.html" 

C:\Users\dle\OneDrive - TransWare Enterprises Inc\Documents\Code Blocks workspaces\Fortran\reportgen>"M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /i "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv"  1>"D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-TWE.html" 

I have verified via GDB that my commands are not being truncated in the system call.
With the very vague the error message from Windows, I at at a loss to understand what the possible [mis]interaction there is with cmd and the system call, and what path is "invalid".  Obviously, both the input file directory and output file directory is being found as a batch file.
I was hoping one of you folks may spot something to further my debugging. I could create individual batch files in the loop and execute them one after the other, but that is the long way around.
I have noticed there is a "1" before the ">" in the batch file output that I assume is cmd specifying that tool the output stdout is being redirected to a file by the ">". I don't know if that is an indication of the cause of the issue.

I suspect M: is a network drive and not connected for the process. Verify dir c:\not.exist to verify the method is working (you should get "file not found"), then dir m:\not.exist. If the drive is connected, you also get "file not found", else you get "invalid path". That the parser corrects the incomplete > to the correct form 1> is a sign that it is recognized correctly. No fault with the >.

Might depend on which Fortran version you are using. GNU documentation appears not to mention parameters, and requires the command within double-quotes (ie entire command, where the executable-name (etc) would also appear to need its own double-quotes - insufficient examples to tell :() Intel appears to also want double-quotes whereas IBM appears to want single-quotes surrounding the OS-command-to-be-executed. (Just a first shot, looking at the first returns from Googling fortran EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE)

Open a command prompt window, run cmd /? and read the output usage help. Most applications run %ComSpec% /c … (with call of function system) which means C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c  …. It is important to know for that reason  the rules used by cmd.exe to interpret the arguments after option /C (or option /K). If the first argument string is enclosed in ", it is in most cases best to enclose the entire command line additionally in ". explorer.exe inserts additionally a space after first ".

Try ""M:\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /f "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv" 1>"D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-FLU.html"" or ""\\HostName\SharedFolderName\FAHA\bin\qbtp_win86.exe" /b /f "D:\Report_generator\QBT_csv_files\timesheet_report_2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31.csv" 1>"D:\Report_generator\Fortran Reports\qbtp-2022-01-01_thru_2022-01-31-FLU.html""

If you want help debugging a Fortran subroutine call, then you should show the Fortran subroutine call.

Thanks I will try each of the dirs to see what I get.

'call execute_command_line(trim(command),exitstat=retcode,cmdmsg=errormsg)' The contents of command is each of the command lines in the post. The return code is a '1'

All of the directories do show as available with the 'dir'commands. I should have been more clear in my post. I'm not executing each command with 'cmd'. I'm just passing the command itself to execute_command_line just as it would be typed on a windows command line.

It appears that adding a second pair of double quotes around the entire command has done the trick.  Thanks to all who helped. And thanks Mofi for that tip on using the correct cmd if I use that in my code. That would be a major security hole, if I did not.

Don’t know about  Fortran, but this recent DosTips topic just might help you resolve your issue.
